# javascript encodeURIComponent equivalent in php

Tags: php, javascript, urlencode

I need to convert `%F3%BE%AE%A2` to this char "" in PHP. When I tried using

```
rawurldecode('%F3%BE%AE%A2');
```

then it gives 2 chars instead of 1 char.

How can I convert it properly?

**EDIT:**
To be more specific it's an UTF-16 surrogate char.it gives `\udbba\udfa2` in javascript.Now 
if i want to send data via javascript API then i could easily send "" as a single character.
But for security reasons i need to use PHP.That's where the problem starts.Decoding `'%F3%BE%AE%A2'` with `rawurldecode() along with utf-8 header` doesn't seem to be giving me the char i want.
Wish i have explained it.Thanks for your appreciations.

Comment: what's PHP using as its output character set? If you're outputting in UTF-8 but the display page is ISO8859 or whatever, then you'll get garbage.

Comment: i am trying to send converted data into a api call.so it's not like writting to a file.So is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is PHP perhaps using UTF-16 internally? Since your character is outside the BMP, it will be represented as two code units in UTF-16. The default reported "length" of a string often counts code units instead of characters. Which two particular characters do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `rawurldecode()` is giving you the correct result. That character consists of four bytes when encoded in utf-8 and the rule in url encoding is to convert each byte to %XX notation. rawurldecode() is giving you back those 4 bytes but probably you have not set your page's encoding to utf-8 so your browser is misinterpreting those bytes. add this to your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and you should see the right character.

---

This is a test page I made:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo rawurldecode('%F3%BE%AE%A2'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

what I see in my browser:

exactly the character you want to see.

Comment: well i used header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); in php.Yet things remain same.

Comment: @neo-nant Look at the test I just did. `rawurldecode()` is working just fine, you should look somewhere else for the source of your problem.